# Add padding on page load and resize

Tags: jquery, pageload, onresize

I calculate the padding of an element and add it on resize. Now, I would like to add it also on page load. How can I do that?

[Live demo](https://www.dstruning.com/)

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var widthWindow = $(window).width();
    var widthContainer = $("#container").width();
    var calculatePadding = (widthWindow - widthContainer) / 2;
    $("#container").css({
        "padding-top":calculatePadding,
        "padding-bottom":calculatePadding
    });
}).resize();
```

Comment: Are you trying to center the elements?

Comment: put function inside `$(function  () {  /*here...*/ });`

Comment: No, I don't want to center the elements. The code works fine, I just want to run it also on page load (besides on resize).

Comment: The code adds padding (top, bottom) to the child elements based on the space between window and parent element. It is simply for a well-balanced look.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
<body onload="resize()">
```

In Javascript:

```
function resize(){
    //write your stuff here
}
```

(OR) the jQuery way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind your handler to the load event:

```
var handler = function () {
    var widthWindow = $(window).width();
    var widthContainer = $("#container").width();
    var calculatePadding = (widthWindow - widthContainer) / 2;
    $("#container").css({
        "padding-top":calculatePadding,
        "padding-bottom":calculatePadding
    });
};

$(window).resize(handler)
$(window).load(handler)
```

Or a bit more elegant in my opinion:

```
$(window).on('load, resize', handler)
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, check my updated live demo.

Comment: That doesn't work at all... weird. On what browser are you? I am on Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133

Comment: Im also on Chrome 57. You also can try this solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/4xjdopc9/4/

Comment: Also doesn't work... mmm. Any idea why it doesn't work at all here?